# UML profile for BPMN models used for business processes

Tags: uml, profile, bpmn

I am new to BPMN and do not know where to start.

How do we  design a UML profile for BPMN models used for business 
processes? Can someone explain the steps for this:

- Design the domain model describing the BPMN concepts
- Define a UML profile by mapping the BPMN domain concepts to UML
- Apply the profile to some given examples.

What tools I should use to do the above.

Answer (score 3):

I had an assignment to convert a limited BPMN to a UML profile. Here are some references that you might find useful:

[UML Profile for BPMN 2 Processes](http://www.conradbock.org/omg/bmi/12-02-01.pdf)

The document follows these specifications:

[BPMN 2.0 Specification](http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/2.0/), [UML 2.4.1 Specification](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.4.1/),[QVT 1.1 Specification](http://www.omg.org/spec/QVT/1.1/) and [XML Schema 1.0](http://www.w3.org/XML/Schema/)

[Here's a QVT](http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMNProfile/20121112/UMLProfileToBPMN.qvt) model to transform the BPMN model to UML. Just as a word of caution, initially, the BPMN concepts look very similar to an UML Activity diagram. But mapping all concepts of BPMN to UML is not a trivial exercise and might take a while.

Also, you could use eclipse's GMF to make your transformation as I thought it was doable with the documents available. [Here's](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Graphical_Modeling_Framework/Tutorial/BPMN) a tutorial on using the BPMN

Comment: Thanks Anshuman. I actually used: Eclipse Modeling Tools IDE with papyrus pulgin (to define the domain model (class diagram) and UML profile extension) and BPMN2 plugin for its diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the concrete steps will depends on the tools you will use.
Have you choose it?
Concernning profile I use [Modelio](http://www.modelio.org/) or [Eclipse UML2](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/?project=uml2) but I guess that most of UML2 tools be fine.

Comment: Thanks for replaying. I actually do not have a clear idea about BPMN and profiles. I found this tool: http://www.sparxsystems.com/ (Enterpris Architect). It seems a good one for BPMN and UML. There is one month free trial to download.

Comment: yes it should be fine. Try it and other it order to find the one which feels fine.